# Calculate Sum of all Adjacent Cells in Matrix in OpenMP

Tags: performance, matrix, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a matrix A whose first row and first column is set to 1 and all remaining elements are 0. Starting from element A[1][1], I want to apply a formula to calculate and store the sum of all the adjacent cells.

```
for (i=1;i<n;i++){
    for (j=1;j<n;j++){
       tmp = A[i][j];
       A[i][j]= 0.2*(A[i][j] + A[i][j-1] + A[i-1][j] + A[i][j+1] + A[i+1][j]);
       diff += fabs(A[i][j] - tmp);
     }
```

I am doing 50 iterations over this piece of code. I want to parallelize it using OpenMP. I tried writing reduction just above outerloop but it worsened the running time.

```
for(k=0; k<50; k++){
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:diff)
for (i=1;i<n;i++){
 for (j=1;j<n;j++){
   tmp = A[i][j];
   A[i][j]= 0.2*(A[i][j] + A[i][j-1] + A[i-1][j] + A[i][j+1] + A[i+1][j]);
   diff += fabs(A[i][j] - tmp);
 }
}
```

I am not sure how should I go about parallelize the nested loop. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please provide actual measurement results, system specifications, and most importantly a [mcve]. It's not even clear what data type `A` is in your case. Stencil codes are one of the most often used examples for parallelism - what research have you done?

Comment: C or C++? add the corresponding tag

Comment: You have explicit Read After Write dependence, as each loop iteration reads an update from the previous.  Even the single thread partial optimization is handled differently by various compilers.  As mentioned above, this question is dealt with all the time in stencil codes.  The small size of your problem makes modification for parallelism of doubtful value.